# Getting position of TextView in TableLayout Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I currently have a table layout in android. This is set as a Time Table and looks like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false" >
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blank"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mon"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/monday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tues"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/tuesday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wed"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/wednesday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thurs"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/thursday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fri"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/friday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sat"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/Saturday" />

    <TextView## Heading ##
        android:id="@+id/sun"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/Sunday" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/nine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nineone"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ninetwo"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ninethree"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ninefour"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ninefive"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ninesix"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nineseven"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ten"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/ten" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tenone"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tentwo"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tenthree"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tenfour"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tenfive"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tensix"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tenseven"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eleven"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/eleven" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elevenone"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eleventwo"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eleventhree"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elevenfour"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elevenfive"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elevensix"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elevenseven"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twelve"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/twelve" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twelveone"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twelvetwo"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twelvethree"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twelvefour"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twelvefive"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twelvesix"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twelveseven"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/one" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oneone"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/onetwo"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/onethree"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/onefour"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/onefive"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/onesix"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oneseven"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/two" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twoone"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twotwo"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twothree"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twofour"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twofive"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twosix"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twoseven"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/three" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threeone"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threetwo"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threethree"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threefour"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threefive"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threesix"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/threeseven"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/four" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fourone"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fourtwo"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fourthree"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fourfour"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fourfive"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foursix"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fourseven"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="@string/five" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fiveone"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fivetwo"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fivethree"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fivefour"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fivefive"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fivesix"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fiveseven"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

When a user clicks on a cell in the App I am wanting to be able to get the position of the exact cell they have clicked. I am get to get the column id but I am unable to get the full position. My code is the following

```
  public class TimeTable extends Activity {
  TextView tv;
  TableRow row;
  String dayName;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_table);
    TableLayout group = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    row = (TableRow) group.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
      row = (TableRow) group.getChildAt(i);
      for (int j = 0; j < row.getChildCount(); j++) {
        tv = (TextView) row.getChildAt(j);
        registerForContextMenu(tv);
        tv.setId(j);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(v.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Anyone know how I can get the full position? Thanks

Comment: Toast Message is showing when clicking on TextView or not?. and you will need to set `tv.setClickable(true);`.

Comment: u can prefer gridview instead of table layout.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply but yes the toast message appears. It displays the position of the column but I am wanting to get the row and the column position.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion : We can get the position of the cell using the loop which is iterating. As it iterates it reaches to every new cell with specific column and row. 
This would work for you.

```
              TableLayout group = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
              row = (TableRow) group.getChildAt(0);
              for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) 
              {
                        row = (TableRow) group.getChildAt(i);
                        for (int j = 0; j < row.getChildCount(); j++)
                        {
                                   tv = (TextView) row.getChildAt(j);
                                   registerForContextMenu(tv);
                                   tv.setId(j);
                                   tv.setOnClickListener(onClick(tv,i,j));
                        }
              }

              View.OnClickListener onClick(final TextView tc,final int row,final int col)  {
                         return new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      public void onClick(View v) {

                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    //use col and row as position of the cell together.
                                 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),                     Integer.toString(v.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                toast.show();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a distinct tag to your each textview so that you can refer it lately.

also add this :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in your tablelayout in the xml file, this will give you the correct position of textview.

Answer (score -1):

Try List view instead of table layout. It has a method to scrolls to respective position.

```
    listview.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```